# Android App to stream IP Camera

Tags: java, android, android-studio, video-streaming, ip-camera

```
    package com.example.drexsprint.ardusecuv20;


    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;




    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);}


        public void goToLeft(View view) {
            goToUrl("http://10.0.1.16/?button2");
        }

        public void goToRight(View view) {
            goToUrl("http://10.0.1.16/?button3");
        }

        public void goToTemp(View view) {
            goToUrl("http://10.0.1.16/?button1");
        }

        public void goToHum(View view) {
            goToUrl("http://10.0.1.16/button1");
        }

        public void goToPic(View view) {
            goToUrl("http://10.0.1.6/image.jpg");
        }

        private void goToUrl(String url) {
            Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse(url);
            Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
            startActivity(launchBrowser);
        }

}


---------------- Android Manifest Code-----------------------------

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.drexsprint.ardusecuv20">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>

------------------------activity_main.xml-------------------------------------

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.example.drexsprint.ardusecuv20.MainActivity">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="87dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Show Humidty"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:onClick="goToHum"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button4"
            android:textColor="#101dae"
            android:backgroundTint="#d87c25" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="78dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Rotate Left"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:cursorVisible="true"
            android:linksClickable="true"
            android:onClick="goToLeft"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button"
            android:textColor="#101dae"
            android:backgroundTint="#d87c25" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Rotate Right"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="0.38"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="goToRight"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button3"
            android:textColor="#101dae"
            android:backgroundTint="#d87c25" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="86dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Show Temprt"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:onClick="goToTemp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textColor="#101dae"
            android:backgroundTint="#d87c25" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="86dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Take a Photo"
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:onClick="goToPic"
            android:layout_above="@+id/button"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button"
            android:textColor="#101dae"
            android:longClickable="true"
            android:backgroundTint="#d87c25" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I'm trying to create an android app to stream my IP Camera, D-link 930L,the IP address is 10.0.1.6,the IP to display video is http://10.0.1.6/video.cgi.
The above code is the app I'm trying to create it already have some buttons that takes you the the website i create, but I want to design the app to be able to stream the video in the main window.The IP Camera ask for Username and Password authentication to stream. I need help to write the code to achieve the stream in the app tried to read and search but lead me to nowhere, I appreciate any help.
I'm Using android Studio 1.5.1 on OSX MAC El Captain.

[image: App that I'm trying to design]